# how to call this with libraries that changing the default this?

Tags: javascript, interact.js

so I started to using [interactjs](http://interactjs.io/)
and I have this simple code:

```
class example {
    registerTouchEvents() {
        var self = this;
        interact('.touchy').draggable({
            onstart: self.onStart,
        });
    }

    onStart(event) {
        this.someAction();//<-- not working as this is interact object
    }

    someAction() {
        console.log('touch has been started') //<-- I need to call this function
    }

}
```

is there someway of calling the current object without using global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the handler where you declare "self":

```
class example {
    registerTouchEvents() {
        var self = this
          , onStart = function onStart(event) {
                self .someAction();
            }
          ;
        interact('.touchy').draggable({
            onstart: onStart,
        });
    }

    someAction() {
        console.log('touch has been started') //<-- I need to call this function
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks simple solution